# One hook per thread allowed Error MessageBoxManager.Register()

Tags: c#, runtime-error, messagebox

i get this runtime error "One hook per thread allowed" when using  MessageBoxManager.Register() to rename messagebox buttons in c#
 the code:

```
 MessageBoxManager.Yes = "نعم";
        MessageBoxManager.No = "إلغاء";
        MessageBoxManager.Register();
```

anyone can help??

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
MessageBoxManager.Unregister();
```

Before attempting to register again

This is to prevent multiple registrations on the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Akatsuki,

I assume you are using the MessageBoxManger from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox).

I used the same and faced the issue as you mentioned.

In the source code available on the aforementioned link, check the Register() method, the exception is arising from there.

In essence, you can use the Register() method only once per thread. If I'm not wrong, your MessageBoxManager.Register() is being executed more than once and as a consequence the exception.

Make sure it executes only once.
One way to acheive this is using a boolean.

Example:
`bool isMsgBoxRegistered = false;
    if (!isMsgBoxRegistered)
    {
        MessageBoxManager.Yes = "نعم";
        MessageBoxManager.No = "إلغاء";
        MessageBoxManager.Register();
        isMsgBoxRegistered = true;
    }`

**EDIT :**

The above given solution is just a temporary workaround. In cases, where it would be used more than once the exception (mentioned in the title) would occur.

To overcome this, the best solution is to use MessageBoxManager.UnRegister() after the usage of the MessageBoxManager is completed.

Comment: @Akatsuki: Did you try the above? Hope it helped you. If it did, please mark it as answered. If it dint, post the problem that you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code worked!

```
MessageBoxManager.Unregister();
```

Comment: As soon as you're done with the message box you can use it. Ex:  MessageBoxManager.Yes = "Option 1";
        MessageBoxManager.No = "Option 2";
        MessageBoxManager.Register();
        isMsgBoxRegistered = true; 

//Some code about if message box result = option 1, do this
//Else Do that

MessageBoxManager.Unregister();

After unregistering, it goes back to the default and you can change the buttons again.